# react native mapbox getCenter not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-mapbox-gl

I have a problem with this lib.
I am trying to get the current center coordinate from the map by (onPress), but none to display,

```
agree = async () => {
  const center = await this._map.getCenter();
  console.warn(center);
}
```

the map code.

```
<MapboxGL.MapView
  ref={(c) => this._map = c}
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  zoomLevel={15}
  centerCoordinate={[-122.084, 37.422]}>
</MapboxGL.MapView>
```

and I am using onPress like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.button}
  onPress={this.agree.bind(this)}
>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>NYC</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Any Help?

Comment: You dont need to bind it, as you are using an arrow function. `onPress={this.agree}` will do fine.

Comment: are you getting any error or warning ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done like(using navigator) :

```
getCurrentLocation = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
            console.log("lng:"+pos.coords.longitude + "lat:"+pos.coords.latitude); 
            //goto your current location 
            this._map.setCamera({
                centerCoordinate: [pos.coords.longitude, pos.coords.latitude],
                zoom: 17
            });
        });
    }
```

Official docs : [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation)